# Flutter SfCartesianChart Not Showing X . Y Axis

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to show price and date in `SfCartesianChart`. It shows me blank chart
Pl check the json as well. I am trying to show price and date for the products in the line chart.

```
    List<SalesData> chartData = [];

      Container(
            height: 250,
            width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(2),
                ),
                color: Color(0xff232d37)),
            child: FutureBuilder(
                future: getJsonFromFirebase(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return SfCartesianChart(primaryXAxis: 
             CategoryAxis(),
                        //  tooltipBehavior: _tooltipBehavior,
                        series: <LineSeries<SalesData, String>>[
                          LineSeries<SalesData, String>(
                              dataSource: chartData,
                              xValueMapper: (SalesData sales, _) =>
                                  sales.date,
                              yValueMapper: (SalesData sales, _) =>
                                  sales.price)
                        ]);
                  } else {
                    return Center(child: 
            CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                })),



       Future<String> getJsonFromFirebase() async {
       String url = "https://someurl.price.php";
       http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
        return response.body;
              }

         Future loadSalesData() async {
        final String jsonString = await getJsonFromFirebase();
        final dynamic jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
        for (Map<String, dynamic> i in jsonResponse)
       chartData.add(SalesData.fromJson(i));
             }

       class SalesData {
       SalesData(this.date, this.price);

        final String date;
        final int price;

      factory SalesData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
       return SalesData(
           parsedJson['date'].toString(),
           parsedJson['price'],
        );
        }
          }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must retrieve the chartData -- > `if (snapshot.hasData) { loadSalesData()`
and parse your price `double.parse(parsedJson['price'])`